# PHP convert docx file to pdf

Tags: php, com, openoffice.org, phpword

I am using PHP as a backend end, I generate a `Docx` file on the backend and I want to send it to the frontend to make the user print it directly without downloading it.

So I wanted to convert the `Docx` file to `PDF` and put it on the server so I can send its link to the frontend to make the user able to view it and print it.

But I am not able to convert from `Docx` to `pdf`, can anyone tell me an easy way to convert from `Docx` to `pdf`, or if anyone has an alternative way to do the whole process.

I am using `PHPWord` to generate the `Docx` files from templates.

***Attempts:***

a) I tried to use `PHPWord` to convert the `Docx` file to an `HTML` file but it generates a blank file.

b) I tried to use `COM` with `OpenOffice` but the following error appeared:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error.
> C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout

c) I tried to use COM with `Word.application`, but I received Access denied.

***Note:*** I am a beginner at PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices:

1. Go to GitHub and try to find a package (written in PHP) that converts your need.
2. Write a little service to communicate another binary that can do this job. You can use something like [this](https://github.com/yeokm1/docs-to-pdf-converter) or [this](https://github.com/KerimG/node-DocTo).
3. You can write your own solution but I do not recommend doing it.

Also, you can check [this article](https://medium.com/medialesson/convert-files-to-pdf-using-microsoft-graph-azure-functions-20bc84d2adc4) and build it on top of Azure serverless.